# How to remove Typescript assert when using npm run build?

Tags: typescript, npm, assert, npm-run

What is the best way to remove Typescript asserts so that a production build created using 
`npm run build` is assert free?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The fastest solution I know is to use [assert-plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/assert-plus) on your project.

You can easily deactivate assertion according to your environment (production, development,..).

Comment: In my opinion when you deactivate the assertion thanks to the environment variable, the function is not removed but just content of the function return void. There is still a problem, the evaluation of the condition is still present in the call of `assert(condition)`.
Did I miss something in the library ?